# Keep query string in url

Tags: event-observer, magento-1, redirect

I am using the event `controller_action_predispatch` and would like if the url contains `?doThis=this` to keep that query in the next url that is load by magento (clicking on another product for example).

```
$url =  "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";

Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url. '?doThis=this')->sendResponse();
```

doesn't work as the url remains the same. the event fires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
public function yourObserver(Varien_Event_Observer $event)
{

     //current url with one more parameter 'doThis = this'
     $url = Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array(
          '_use_rewrite' => true, 
          '_forced_secure' => true, 
          'doThis' => 'this'
     ));

     //redirect to custom url
     $event->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
}
```

**OR**

You can also try this.

```
public function yourObserver(Varien_Event_Observer $event)
{

     //current url with one more parameter 'doThis = this'
     $url = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl() . '?doThis=this';

     //redirect to custom url
     $event->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
}
```